# How to access a table with username with special characters in Oracle sql Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, select, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have the following usernames/schema:

> 1. shopping
> 2. shops[shopping]

In both users I created a table named "SHOP_TAKE_CART", I use shopping for testing purposes and  shops[shopping] to publish it.
Now I want to compare both tables to see if the data I have in the user shops[shopping] is the same in shopping, but I can't...

When I open connection in shopping and execute the following select:

```
Select * from shops[shopping].SHOP_TAKE_CART;
```

shows me the following error:

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

And when I open connection in shops[shopping] and try:

```
Select * from shopping.SHOP_TAKE_CART;
```

shows me the data of shops[shopping] and not the data of shopping.

There's any way I can do a select of shops[shopping]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need double quotes - as defined by the SQL standard:

```
select * 
from "shops[shopping]".shop_take_cart;
```

Comment: And I might add, for the OP, that any time you require double-quotes around an object name, you have made a very bad choice of object names.

Comment: And using square brackets in a user name is especially bad because the string looks like a proxy user connection.